# Cloud Functions - Use global variables

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I have a function `cloudFunctionCall` in my cloud-function setup that is invoked on every cloud function call.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const mysql = require("mysql");

function cloudFunctionCall(asyncFunc) {
  return functions
    .region(region)
    .https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {
      try {
        const pool = mysql.createPool(getConfig(context));
        const result = await asyncFunc(data, pool);
        pool.end();
        res.send(result);
      } catch (err) {
        log("A promise failed to resolve", err);
        res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    });
}

export const func1 = cloudFunctionCall(_func1);
export const func2 = cloudFunctionCall(_func2);
```

`context` and therefore `pool` defines to which database an invoked function needs to talk to which might change on every cloud function call. Now I want to avoid passing `pool` as a parameter to `asyncFunc` since it is not actually required for the function logic and makes the functions more verbose.

Now my question: Is it safe to define `pool` as a global variable that gets updated on every cloud function call like the following?

```
//...
let pool;

function cloudFunctionCall(asyncFunc) {
  return functions
    .region(region)
    .https.onCall(async (data: any, context: any) => {
      try {
        pool = mysql.createPool(getConfig(context));
        const result = await asyncFunc(data, pool);
//...
```

I understand that every exported function is hosted in it's own environment but what would happen if `func1` would get executed twice in quick succession on different databases? Could it happen that the second invocation overwrites `pool` that was set by the first invocation so that the latter one executes on the wrong database?

If so, is there another way to avoid passing `pool` as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Function invocations run in strict isolation of each other: each container will only ever have one execution at a time. So there is no chance of function invocations overwriting the value of your global for each other.

Answer (score -2):

A global variable value is shared across all function invocations of the same instance:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-tips-scopes

So function invocations are not  isolated w.r.t. global variables.

In the google documentation, when they state 'isolation' they mean only for instances, not function invocations.

See also at 1:27:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mjfI0FYP7Y&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM&index=1

Comment: instead of providing links please explain what does it mean. Many a times questioner see video themselves but can't find answer that's why they come to stack overflow.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34227131)

Comment: The links are only to backup the comments that I have written.  The comments stand without the links.  Next time I will leave out links.